# Should you create Express and React on the same port?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to make a chat application.

Frontend will have React and the Express backend with MongoDB.
Client messaging will work on Socket.IO.

What is the best way to link backend and frontend, on the same port, or on different?

And is it worth having different repositories for the frontend and backend?

Comment: You can not have two applications running on the same port

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways:

- Express as react static files server: with this approach, you will need only one port and you will serve everything with express. For example, express can use port 80.
- Another server in front of your system:  with this approach, you will need another server like Nginx which can serve react static files and forward backend requests to your server on another port. For example Nginx on port 80 and express on port 8080.
- Two different applications with different domains